# Assign weights to develop a modified index, in case that the index is a quotient such as A/(B-C)?

Tags: weights

I am trying to modify a water use monitoring index which has a form such as A/(B-C), taking into account the importance of each one of the variable (A, B, C). To identify the importance weights, I have as available input the answers of experts that indicate that in a likert scale (1 not important, 5 very important): A has a median of 3.5, B has a median value of 1.5 and C a median of 4. Are there any suggestions on how I can embed these results in the ratio index?
My main concern is that the index in a quotient